# Partition of a space and a strictly positive measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a Polish metric space (with a distance $d$). [We know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367848/every-separable-complete-metric-space-has-a-countable-partition-into-nonempty-bo) for each $\epsilon>0$, $X$ can be partitioned into a countable number of non-empty Borel subsets, $\{B_n\}$, whose diameters do not exceed $\epsilon$. Given a strictly positive measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal{B}(X))$ (i.e., $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)=X$), can we assume that $\mu(B_n)>0$ for each $n$?

I think this is true because if $\mu(B_n)=0$ for some $n$ and $x\in B_n$, there exists another set $B_m$ in the partition such that $x\notin B_m$, $d(x,B_m)=0$, and $\mu(B_m)>0$. (Since $\mu$ is strictly positive, $\mu(B_{\tau}(x))>0$ for any $\tau>0$.)

---

[This paper](https://www.mathnet.ru/links/307296876fd3b36d830c26ff2c17e710/mmo257.pdf) (an English version was published [here](https://www.google.nl/books/edition/Transactions_of_the_Moscow_Mathematical/TzXegQLGJ0MC?hl=en&gbpv=0)) shows that there exists an "almost open partition" into Borel sets such that each $B_n$ has a non-empty interior, which solves the problem.

Comment: When you say diameter, do you mean that you are fixing a complete metric in the question?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes.